# Unwanted unlock code screen on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1

Tags: lock-screens, bugs, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

This screen has been appearing lately. It appears in a few seconds after I have inserted a SIM card, rebooted the device, and draw the right pattern or inputted the right unlock code. The screenshot of the unwanted code is below.

Model number: GT-N8000.
Android version: 4.1.2 (stock).

[image: The screenshot of the unwanted unlock screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more unwanted unlock screen. Something might have been wrong with the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a tablet with SIM lock.

You have to unlock your tablet to use another SIM card (or a SIM card from another provider). You have to contact the provider which has sold the tablet for the first time.

Comment: I'd rather say that this tab is not sim-locked to a specific carrier but instead the SIM itself has a PIN protection which needs to be unlocked after a reboot/re-insertion. Change it under **Settings->Security->Setup SIM card lock**

Comment: @ce4, the "Setup SIM card lock" checbox is unchecked. I inserted another SIM card and had to input the same unlock code.